# Deep Learning YOLO Object Detection: How to iterate over cells in a grid defined over the image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the YOLOv2 Object Detection algorithm myself, just to learn how the algorithm works. Of course I will use pre-trained weights to make things faster. I was using the code from the [keras-yolo2](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/Yolo%20Step-by-Step.ipynb) repository as a basis for my own code, but I had a question about how the code related back to the underlying YOLO algorithm.

As I understand it--from a high level--YOLO (You Only Look Once) will:

1. Break the image into an `SxS` grid.
2. For each cell in the grid, conduct classification and assign probabilities to each potential label.
3. Prune the classified boxes based upon whether the box/class confidence exceeds some threshold.

Multiple other things happen after this point, including non-max suppression, etc.

**I was looking at some code in the aforementioned repository to try and figure out how the author actually breaks the image into the `SxS` grid in order to execute the object classification within the cells. Can anyone see where that piece of the algorithm happens in the code below.** It could be that my knowledge of tensorflow is lacking, but I could not tell where this is implemented in the code below. Seems like the initial call to `cell_x = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(GRID_W), [GRID_H]), (1, GRID_H, GRID_W, 1, 1)))` would break down the image into cells, but I don't understand how this would work without looping over each grid cell? I also don't understand how `tf.reshape` and `tf.tile` and `tf.range` work in concert with each other to break down the picture to a cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W = 416, 416
GRID_H,  GRID_W  = 13 , 13
BOX              = 5
CLASS            = len(LABELS)
CLASS_WEIGHTS    = np.ones(CLASS, dtype='float32')
OBJ_THRESHOLD    = 0.3#0.5
NMS_THRESHOLD    = 0.3#0.45
ANCHORS          = [0.57273, 0.677385, 1.87446, 2.06253, 3.33843, 5.47434, 7.88282, 3.52778, 9.77052, 9.16828]

NO_OBJECT_SCALE  = 1.0
OBJECT_SCALE     = 5.0
COORD_SCALE      = 1.0
CLASS_SCALE      = 1.0

BATCH_SIZE       = 16
WARM_UP_BATCHES  = 0
TRUE_BOX_BUFFER  = 50

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mask_shape = tf.shape(y_true)[:4]

    cell_x = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(GRID_W), [GRID_H]), (1, GRID_H, GRID_W, 1, 1)))
    cell_y = tf.transpose(cell_x, (0,2,1,3,4))

    cell_grid = tf.tile(tf.concat([cell_x,cell_y], -1), [BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 5, 1])

    coord_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
    conf_mask  = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
    class_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)

    seen = tf.Variable(0.)
    total_recall = tf.Variable(0.)

    """
    Adjust prediction
    """
    ### adjust x and y      
    pred_box_xy = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., :2]) + cell_grid

    ### adjust w and h
    pred_box_wh = tf.exp(y_pred[..., 2:4]) * np.reshape(ANCHORS, [1,1,1,BOX,2])

    ### adjust confidence
    pred_box_conf = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 4])

    ### adjust class probabilities
    pred_box_class = y_pred[..., 5:]

    """
    Adjust ground truth
    """
    ### adjust x and y
    true_box_xy = y_true[..., 0:2] # relative position to the containing cell

    ### adjust w and h
    true_box_wh = y_true[..., 2:4] # number of cells accross, horizontally and vertically

    ### adjust confidence
    true_wh_half = true_box_wh / 2.
    true_mins    = true_box_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes   = true_box_xy + true_wh_half

    pred_wh_half = pred_box_wh / 2.
    pred_mins    = pred_box_xy - pred_wh_half
    pred_maxes   = pred_box_xy + pred_wh_half       

    intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
    intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
    intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

    true_areas = true_box_wh[..., 0] * true_box_wh[..., 1]
    pred_areas = pred_box_wh[..., 0] * pred_box_wh[..., 1]

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
    iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)

    true_box_conf = iou_scores * y_true[..., 4]

    ### adjust class probabilities
    true_box_class = tf.argmax(y_true[..., 5:], -1)

    """
    Determine the masks
    """
    ### coordinate mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
    coord_mask = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 4], axis=-1) * COORD_SCALE

    ### confidence mask: penelize predictors + penalize boxes with low IOU
    # penalize the confidence of the boxes, which have IOU with some ground truth box < 0.6
    true_xy = true_boxes[..., 0:2]
    true_wh = true_boxes[..., 2:4]

    true_wh_half = true_wh / 2.
    true_mins    = true_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes   = true_xy + true_wh_half

    pred_xy = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_xy, 4)
    pred_wh = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_wh, 4)

    pred_wh_half = pred_wh / 2.
    pred_mins    = pred_xy - pred_wh_half
    pred_maxes   = pred_xy + pred_wh_half    

    intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
    intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
    intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]

    true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]
    pred_areas = pred_wh[..., 0] * pred_wh[..., 1]

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
    iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)

    best_ious = tf.reduce_max(iou_scores, axis=4)
    conf_mask = conf_mask + tf.to_float(best_ious < 0.6) * (1 - y_true[..., 4]) * NO_OBJECT_SCALE

    # penalize the confidence of the boxes, which are reponsible for corresponding ground truth box
    conf_mask = conf_mask + y_true[..., 4] * OBJECT_SCALE

    ### class mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
    class_mask = y_true[..., 4] * tf.gather(CLASS_WEIGHTS, true_box_class) * CLASS_SCALE       

    """
    Warm-up training
    """
    no_boxes_mask = tf.to_float(coord_mask < COORD_SCALE/2.)
    seen = tf.assign_add(seen, 1.)

    true_box_xy, true_box_wh, coord_mask = tf.cond(tf.less(seen, WARM_UP_BATCHES), 
                          lambda: [true_box_xy + (0.5 + cell_grid) * no_boxes_mask, 
                                   true_box_wh + tf.ones_like(true_box_wh) * np.reshape(ANCHORS, [1,1,1,BOX,2]) * no_boxes_mask, 
                                   tf.ones_like(coord_mask)],
                          lambda: [true_box_xy, 
                                   true_box_wh,
                                   coord_mask])

    """
    Finalize the loss
    """
    nb_coord_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(coord_mask > 0.0))
    nb_conf_box  = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(conf_mask  > 0.0))
    nb_class_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(class_mask > 0.0))

    loss_xy    = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_xy-pred_box_xy)     * coord_mask) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_wh    = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_wh-pred_box_wh)     * coord_mask) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_conf  = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(true_box_conf-pred_box_conf) * conf_mask)  / (nb_conf_box  + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_class = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=true_box_class, logits=pred_box_class)
    loss_class = tf.reduce_sum(loss_class * class_mask) / (nb_class_box + 1e-6)

    loss = loss_xy + loss_wh + loss_conf + loss_class

    nb_true_box = tf.reduce_sum(y_true[..., 4])
    nb_pred_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(true_box_conf > 0.5) * tf.to_float(pred_box_conf > 0.3))

    """
    Debugging code
    """    
    current_recall = nb_pred_box/(nb_true_box + 1e-6)
    total_recall = tf.assign_add(total_recall, current_recall) 

    loss = tf.Print(loss, [tf.zeros((1))], message='Dummy Line \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss_xy], message='Loss XY \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss_wh], message='Loss WH \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss_conf], message='Loss Conf \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss_class], message='Loss Class \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], message='Total Loss \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [current_recall], message='Current Recall \t', summarize=1000)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [total_recall/seen], message='Average Recall \t', summarize=1000)

    return loss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Yolo v2`, per say, does not break the images into `13x13` grid, but makes predictions at a grid level instead of pixel level.

The network takes the input image of size `416x416` and outputs `13x13` predictions, each of which is an array that contains class probabilities and box coordinates(a `425` size vector, the actual output size is `13x13x425`). So each of the output `pixel` is seen as a prediction for a region in the input image. For example, the index `[2,3]` of the output corresponds to the prediction (a 425 length vector) for the input image region `(64,96,96,128)`.

The box coordinates which are part of the 425 length vector are encoded relative to the `cell_grid`.

[image]

The `cell_grid` in the code,  just calculates the `mesh grid` of size `13x13` for the entire batch, that will be used to predict the actual coordinates and nothing else.

```
cell_grid = tf.tile(tf.concat([cell_x,cell_y], -1), [BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 5, 1])
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you are saying. So this is where I was unclear--since in all the YOLO pictures they show this picture of the grid. So the CNN will reduce the original image to a `13x13` image--after convolutions and max pooling. Then the algorithm will try to predict the class probabilities and bounding box coordinates for each pixel in the `13x13` reduced image. Can you explain what you mean by the (2,3) and the (64,96,96,128) regions though. Like what is (2,3) in terms of the `13x13` image.

Comment: Edited the above. The inputs are not converted to a 13x13 image and then prediction is applied on the 13x13 image. But instead the CNN reduces the original image to a 13x13x425, where each of the 13x13 is a prediction to a grid in the original image.

Comment: Oh this is great. Yeah, this is making more sense now. Man, I don't know how I missed this in reading the original paper. If you know of any good introductions or tutorials on object detection, please pass them along--though you have already provided so much help already.

Comment: http://christopher5106.github.io/object/detectors/2017/08/10/bounding-box-object-detectors-understanding-yolo.html explains well, note the number of class in the link is 20, so the feature size is (5 anchors * (20 class probs + 5 bounding coordinates)) = 125. In your case its (5 *(80 classes + 5)) = 425.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Yep, I understand the change based upon the 20 classes--haha that much I understand :).